# Simple Set theory question and reference request

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

Let $A\cap (C\cup B)=A\cap B$

Can this be simplified to:

$C\cup B = B$?

How is this correct or wrong?

Also please recommend a good Set theory resource!

Thank You.

Comment: The word "let" is usually used for definitions on individual objects, so it's a bit odd to read "Let $A\cap (C\cup B)=A\cap B$". It would be better to write "*Suppose* $A\cap (C\cup B)=A\cap B$", or "Let $A,B,C$ be sets such that $A\cap (C\cup B)=A\cap B$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong. Counterexample for $C\cup B = B$ (while $A\cap (C\cup B)=A\cap B$):

$A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{1,2\}$ and $C\{1,4\}$

---

$A\cap (C\cup B)=(A\cap C)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B$. This implies $(A\cap C)\subset (A\cap B)$.

---

Refernce for Set Theory: *Thomas Jech*'s book, named "*Set Theory*". See also [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854314/reference-request-descriptive-set-theory).

Comment: How do I develop an intuition for sets? for now, i tink it as a very radical and new concept, and i cant figure out how to make my way through a proof. I also keep inventing erroneous properties of sets like this. So how do i develop a deeper understanding?

Comment: 1- [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) can help you to have intuition, but be careful using it. 2- exercise. 3- exercise... after a while you develop a deeper understanding.